# How to separate out @types within project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack, ts-node

I had a TypeScript project that uses React and Webpack:

```
npm install react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom --save
npm install webpack ts-loader --save-dev
```

I have a typical `webpack.config.js` to build the project. Everything works well.

Then I converted `webpack.config.js` from `.js` to `.ts` following [this article](https://medium.com/webpack/unambiguous-webpack-config-with-typescript-8519def2cac7):

```
npm install ts-node @types/node @types/webpack --save-dev
```

Indeed, `webpack.config.ts` works great.

However, the typedefs between node/webpack and react are seen as in the same space (ie both local and web). For example in my `webpack.config.ts` I should be referencing `@types/node` and not `@types/react`, and in my `src/components/app.tsx` file I should be referencing `@types/react` and not `@types/node`, but in both places the compiler and IDE thinks I use both (at runtime it will blow up). How can I separate these type definitions, so that the right ones are visible to the right files?

Conceptually, I think I just want `@types` from `devDependencies` to only be visible to dev scripts, like `webpack.config.ts`, and files in `src` can only see `@types` from `dependencies`. Is that kind of setup possible?

Comment: All TypeScript definitions should be dev dependencies. TypeScript should not be referenced in any way in production.

Comment: You can control which `@types` packages are used by explicitly specifying them in the `tsconfig.json` file using the [`types` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). You would need separate `tsconfig.json` files for running the build tools and for compiling the app, but with the [`extends` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), that's not too painful.

Comment: @Cristy https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with two separate `tsconfig.json` files, something like:

```
 /webpack.config.ts
 /tsconfig.json
 /src/components/app.tsx
 /src/tsconfig.json
```

Your `/tsconfig.json` is then specific for a Node environment (for building):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2015"], // no DOM
        "types": ["node"]
    }
}
```

And `/src/tsconfig.json` is then for a browser environment:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
        "types": ["react"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... maintaining two `tsconfig.json`s seems reasonable, but `types` is going to become a leaky dependency, I have 34 already...

Comment: `types` is [only for *automatic* types inclusion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types). If you use explicit imports like `import * as React from "react"`, you don't need to specify them in `tsconfig`.

Comment: That helps... but if I don't include something in `types` then auto-import doesn't seem to work...